# "[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..." when try to iterate large array with async.eachLimit and promises

Tags: arrays, node.js, asynchronous, promise, each

I'd like to parse CSV file and then iterate the array.

Function for a file reading:

```
function readLanguagesFile(file) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    converter.fromFile(file, function(err, arrayLanguages) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(arrayLanguages);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Function for iterating:

```
function handleLanguages(langArr) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    async.eachLimit(langArr, 2, function(lang, next) {
      next();
    }, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Execution of the functions:

```
function seedLanguages(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      readLanguagesFile(file)
        .then(handleLanguages)
        .then(function() {
          resolve();
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

Calling the exec function:

```
module.exports.start = function start() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    seedLanguages(languagesFile)
      .then(function() {
        resolve();
      })
      .catch(reportError(reject));
  });
};
```

When I try to handle large file with about 8k rows I get the error "[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..." w/o any additional info. And the iterating is stopped.
I can output the array and it looks ok. But async.eachLimit is stopped after about 2k objects iterating the array.

Could you help me to understand a reason of the issue?
Thank you in advance!